# JSON ["data","pre database"]

Tags: php, android, arrays, json

So, I put my php page to connect to my android app on a hosted server (Hostgator). Now my PHP script for the JSON data seems to not be returning properly.This was working on my wamp server just fine. Example below of issue...

```
["data","pre database"][{"email":"thomas@wiregrass.edu","password":"test","fname":"Thomas","lname":"Cummings","phone":"5052030822","temppass":"15151","alert":"B"}]
```

Any ides as to what I did wrong or what is going on would be appreciated.

PHP script (might be outdated, this project is old):

```
<?php

$user = "ab73953_test";
$pass = "H3@ther78";
$db = "ab73953_testdb";
$out = array('data', 'pre database');
echo json_encode($out);
$db =  mysqli_connect('localhost', $user, $pass, $db) or die("did not work");


$email=$_POST['username'];
$email = "thomas@wiregrass.edu"; // testing 

$qry = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = "'. $email .'"' ;

$result = mysqli_query($db, $qry) or die(" did not query");

$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$output = array();
if($count > 0){
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
 {
   $output[]=$row;

 }

 echo json_encode($output);

}
else 
echo json_encode("Could not find user");

mysqli_close($db);
?>
```

Comment: That is not valid JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not valid JSON. JSON is basically javascript: If the json you generate would be a javascript syntax error, then it's not valid json.

You have two separate `echo json_encode(...)` blocks, so you're producing two entirely separate/distinct json strings. Your output can only be one SINGLE json string.

e.g. `[...][...]` is two separate arrays that have gotten glued together. It's a javascript syntax error, therefore it's also invalid json. If you had something like

```
$arr1 = array(...);
$arr2 = array(...);
echo json_encode(array($arr1, $arr2));
```

you'd end up with

```
[[...],[...]]
```

and be ok

But you have

```
echo json_encode($arr1);
echo json_encode($arr2);
```

and end up with

```
[...][...]
```

which is an outright syntax error.

And note that you're vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: Excellent! Deleted     
    **$out = array('data', 'pre database');
    echo json_encode($out);** and it works now!! Than\k you So So much!! Now I will look into injection issues :)